# In Elasticsearch - Is there a way to combine many completion type under same context?

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

I tried to create suggest index which filter by context (I based on the examples at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/suggester-context.html) 
I want to filter by same context for every document but I don't want to save the duplication of the context per field, My question if there is a better way to do that?

**For Example:**
I have the document :

```
{
   "Name":"Lupidon",
   "Father":"Zeus",
   "context":{
      "favorite_food":[
         "pizza"
      ]
   }
}
```

when **name** and **father** is **completion** type and then I could look for prefix of name or father which in the document contains some favorite food

Comment: Can you show your index mapping as well as the suggest query you're sending?

Comment: @Val I don't have Index mapping, actually I added the example to show what I want to do